# asterisk ask media server to play file

Tags: media, asterisk, agi, windows-media-services

I receive a call in asterisk and I want a Media Server Play a file for caller that a file exist in Media server
how can I do this?
and can you give me a code in Agi that I use ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't force third-party server(WMS) play file by using asterisk.

You can play file on asterisk using Playback command.